# Custom get and set methods on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

Always when i to save a model, i want set an encrypted password, see the code bellow, it works:

```
 private string _senha;
    public string Senha
    {
        get { return _senha; }
        set
        {
            if (null != value)
            {
                _senha = BCryptHelper.HashPassword(value, BCryptHelper.GenerateSalt());
            }
        }
    }
```

But in my AuthController to check the password, it don't work, i think that the model is trying encrypt again before do it, what can i do?

My auth:

```
// POST: Clientes/Login
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection cliente_params)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string Email = cliente_params["Email"].ToString();
            string Senha = cliente_params["Senha"].ToString();
            bool Remember = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(cliente_params["Remember"]));
            Cliente cliente = db.Clientes.Where(p => p.Email.Equals(Email)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (null != cliente)
            {
                string EncryptedPassword = cliente.Senha;
                if (BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(Senha, EncryptedPassword))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(cliente.Email, Remember);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email ou senha incorretos!" + Senha + " - " + EncryptedPassword);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email ou senha incorretos!");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Don't do that; setters should be idempotent.  You should hash it in the callsite.

Comment: In the methods of creating and updating the UsersController for example?

Comment: How are you getting `Senha` variable?

Comment: User user = db.Users.Where(p => p.Email.Equals(Email)).FirstOrDefault();
string EncryptedPassword = user.Senha;

Comment: @DanielLourusso I meant `Senha` variable in here: `BCryptHelper.CheckPassword(Senha, EncryptedPassword)`, can you update your answer with more code from your action method?

Comment: As a side note, it appears you're generating a new salt per hash which means that you'll also have to save off your salt value in order to reproduce the same hash.

Comment: This is not necessary because the CheckPassword the BCrypt method can check without the salt. I think the problem is that it's taking the hash and creating another hash from it to compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get to do it working on the model, to solve, i put my logical code in the controller.